# Does the one-definition-rule force a single static function variable to be created?

Tags: c++, templates, static-variables, one-definition-rule

As an example, consider this header:

```
#include <iostream>

template<bool = true>
struct A {
    A() {
        static int x;
        std::cout << &x << "\n";
    }
};

static A<> a;
```

What if I had two different C++ files including this file - would it print the same address twice, guaranteed? Even more importantly, if `x` was an object of a different type with a non-trivial constructor, would it be guaranteed to only be run once?

Comment: I think thats how singleton pattern are implemented, by return a static variable inside `getInstance`

Comment: @BryanChen Well that was kind of my plan with this (https://gist.github.com/nightcracker/7884976). Still thinking about thread-safity pre-C++11.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard [C++11 14.8/2] says

> Each function template specialization instantiated from a template has its own copy of any static variable.

I assume (and sincerely hope) that member functions of a template class are treated the same way, although I can't find the specific language that says so.

In any case, apart from the usual risks associated with initialising static variables in a multithreaded context, I'm sure this would be fine. `A<true>::A()` (and the internal "`static int A<true>::A::x`") would be marked as weak symbols and one version would be picked at link time, the same as any other template. (Obviously, an instantiation of `A<false>` would be distinct from `A<true>`.)

Edit for comment:

The worry about different translation units seems to be covered by section [3.2/5], defining the ODR:

> If D is a template and is defined in more than one translation unit, then... [providing the definitions are identical]... the program shall behave as if there were a single definition of D.

The actual requirements are a bit more language-lawyery (dependent names at the point of instantiation must be the same, etc etc), but I think this is the bit that puts you in the clear :-)

Comment: I'm slightly confused right now, your quote talks about different specializations, while I'm worried about different translation units (let's assume that the bool is and will always be true).

Comment: @nightcracker Added another bit of standardese that I think covers that :-)